# VBA moving rows to another sheet if first column value matches to a specified cell value

Tags: vba, sorting

I have issue with finding a solution to my excel database sorting problem. I am quite an advanced excel user, but with this issue i gues i have no choice but to dig in VBA, which seems overwhelmingly endless from my VBAnewbie point of view. This is the reason why i decided to look for experienced enthusiasts who migth help me out.

I've searched through multiple forums and answers to this type of issue, but none of those helped me to make my sorting procedure work (well, it is as well the problem of me not knowing the VBA at all and also not having loads of time to play trial and error).

***So here goes:***

I have an Excel sheet called: **BASE** with a lot of data (data fills range from A2:J60000) :

https://www.dropbox.com/s/d2zwdb98idda379/BASE.JPG?dl=0

Then i have a target sheet called: **Class1** :

https://www.dropbox.com/s/kwa0mbyiksytnyo/Class1.JPG?dl=0

I need data sorted if matching a certain value. Not just searching or copying rows, but MOVEing ( or copying/pasteing and then deleting with leaving no empty rows). So the basic Excel Index/Match or V/H Lookup does no good for me at this point.

The procedure steps for me would be:

1. I get data into sheet Base (fot this i dont need VBA) - the data is just plain values and text with no special formating.
2. Then I enter value "X" ( for example: "1" as it shows in Class1 with yellow ) in cell "A1" in target sheet: "Class1"  - also - no VBA
3. *NOW  i need VBA help* :

3.1. to 'go' through the whole **column A** in sheet **BASE**

3.2. look for value matching the cells A1 value in target sheet.

3.3. look for an empty row to which move to this matching data row ( To not overwrite the existing data in target sheet)

3.4.  And finally to move these 'value matching' rows ( or range A2:J2 ( A3:J3, and etc.)) to a target sheets coresponding columns.  ( For example: Moving A2:J2  to target sheets A6:J6, because ists empty).

Any help regarding this issue is very appreciated! Because it would resque me out of my excel misery :)

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this perhaps?

```
Sub SO

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set shTarget = Sheets("Target Sheet") 'Change as required
Set shBase = Sheets("BASE") 'Change as required

For i = shBase.Range("A" & shBase.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
  If shBase.Cells(i, 1).Value = shTarget.Cells(1, 1).Value Then
    shBase.Rows(i).EntireRow.Copy _
    Destination:= shTarget.Rows(shTarget.Cells(shTarget.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1).EntireRow
    shBase.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp
  End If
Next i

Application.CutCopyMode = False

Set shTarget = Nothing
Set shBase = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: It works perfectly, with one exception: blank rows does not delete.

Comment: And maybe there is an extra code line which could hide excel window flashing while sorting data?