# cope entire row if values match

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to build a macro which will copy the current row to a new sheet if the value (REPORT ID) from column S matches the REPORT ID from Column A in sheet2. I assume it could be done with a custom filter/VBA macro. Could you please point me in the right direction? Thanks for help.

Regards,
Damian

Comment: This can definitely be done using VBA. Start by recording a macro and see what it does. Then start tinkering to make it more useful for your use case. Then come back when you have more specific questions.

Comment: Welcome. It would help if you can post Your effort in the matter since SO aint a free code writing page. With some googling you would find a pointer in the direction you need to like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27402157/vba-moving-rows-to-another-sheet-if-first-column-value-matches-to-a-specified-ce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume all of your three sheets are in the same workbook and this one is the current one open.

**If you want value from Column S in Sheet1 to match with Column A in Sheet2 at the same row**

```
Sub CopyEntireRowIfMatch()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet        'your first worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet        'your second worksheet
    Dim dstWs As Worksheet      'your destination sheet
    Dim colNameSheet1 As String 'your column name in sheet 1
    Dim colNameSheet2 As String 'your column name in sheet 2
    Dim count As Double
    Dim colNumSheet1 As Integer

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws1 = wb.Sheets("Name of your first sheet")
    Set ws2 = wb.Sheets("Name of your second sheet")
    Set dstWs = wb.Sheets("Name of your destination sheet")
    colNameSheet1 = "S"
    colNameSheet2 = "A"

    count = 1
    colNumSheet1 = Range(colNameSheet1 & "1").Column

    For Each cell In ws1.Range(colNameSheet1 & "1:" & colNameSheet1 & WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws1.Columns(colNumSheet1)))
        If (cell = ws2.Range(colNameSheet2 & cell.Row)) Then
            ws1.Rows(cell.Row).EntireRow.Copy
            dstWs.Range("A" & count).PasteSpecial
            count = count + 1
        End If
    Next cell

    Set ws1 = Nothing
    Set ws2 = Nothing
    Set dstWs = Nothing

End Sub
```

**If you want value from Column S in Sheet1 to match with any row in Column A of Sheet2**

```
Sub CopyEntireRowIfMatch()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet        'your first worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet        'your second worksheet
    Dim dstWs As Worksheet      'your destination sheet
    Dim colNameSheet1 As String 'your column name in first sheet
    Dim colNameSheet2 As String 'your column name in second sheet
    Dim count As Double
    Dim colNumSheet1 As Integer
    Dim colNumSheet2 As Integer

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws1 = wb.Sheets("Name of your first sheet")
    Set ws2 = wb.Sheets("Name of your second sheet")
    Set dstWs = wb.Sheets("Name of your destination sheet")
    colNameSheet1 = "S"
    colNameSheet2 = "A"

    count = 1
    colNumSheet1 = Range(colNameSheet1 & "1").Column
    colNumSheet2 = Range(colNameSheet2 & "1").Column

    For Each cell In ws1.Range(colNameSheet1 & "1:" & colNameSheet1 & WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws1.Columns(colNumSheet1)))
        For Each cellInSecondSheet In ws2.Range(colNameSheet2 & "1:" & colNameSheet2 & WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws2.Columns(colNumSheet2)))
            If (cell = cellInSecondSheet) Then
                ws1.Rows(cell.Row).EntireRow.Copy
                dstWs.Range(colNameSheet2 & count).PasteSpecial
                count = count + 1
            End If
        Next cellInSecondSheet
    Next cell

    Set ws1 = Nothing
    Set ws2 = Nothing
    Set dstWs = Nothing

End Sub
```

---

### Usage

Replace **Name of your first sheet** in `Set ws1 = wb.Sheets("Name of your first sheet")` by the name of your sheet in your workbook.

Replace **Name of your second sheet** in `Set ws2 = wb.Sheets("Name of your second sheet")` by the name of the sheet to compare values (sheet2 in your example).

Replace **Name of your destination sheet** in `Set dstWs = wb.Sheets("Name of your destination sheet")` by the name of the sheet you want to paste the entire row once it's matched.

Replace **S** in `colNameSheet1 = "S"` by the name of the column in your first sheet.

Replace **A** in `colNameSheet2 = "A"` by the name of the column in your second sheet.

Comment: @Dmglej Now that I am reading your question more carefully, did you mean that if a row in the first sheet match with ANY row in the second sheet you'll copy-paste it ?

Comment: Sheet 2 has only one column - the copy paste should work each time cell S from Sheet 1 matches the same value from column A - not just any row. I think the macro should work just fine - I'll be testing it now

Comment: @Dmglej I added a second function in case the first one wasn't doing what you need. The second function will copy your row if the value in column S in sheet1 match with any row in column A of sheet2. Tell me if my solution work as you wanted.

Comment: It's brilliant - I'll try adding a UserForm to make it a bit more user-friendly but it works perfecty